# Entire Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am facing the following problem.

Let $f$ and $g$ be analytic functions in $|z|<1$, with
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n,\quad g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nz^n$$
such that $a_n\geq 0$, $b_n\geq 0$ and $f(z)g(z)=e^{z-1}$. Prove that $f$ and $g$ are entire functions.

After comparing the coefficient, I get
$$a_nb_0+\cdots+a_0b_n=\frac{1}{n!e}.$$
I have tried to use this to prove that the radius of convergent is infinity, but I stuck with the expression above. What is a good approach to this question?

Comment: $0\leq a_n\leq \frac{1}{n!b_0e}$

Comment: O I see, from this, I can conclude $\lim a_n=0$ and so $\lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=0$ and hence radius of convergence is $\infty$.

Comment: From this you can conclude more. Compute what you want, the radius of convergence of $f$.

Comment: $\lim a_n=0$ doesn't imply $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n=0$. That is a wrong deduction.

Comment: Opps, I over look it, sorry.

Comment: It should be $\limsup a_n^{1/n}=0$.

Comment: No, the problem is not that. The problem is that neither $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n=0$ not $\linsup a_n^{1/n}=0$ follow from $\lim a_n=0$. The latter does follow, though, from the inequality in my first comment.

Comment: I know, I just mean one can obtain $\limsup a_n=0$ from your inequality but not from the conclusion $\lim a_n=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ABC noted, due to  the nonnegativity of coefficients, the identity 
$$a_nb_0+\cdots+a_0b_n=\frac{1}{n!e}\tag{1}$$ 
implies 
$$a_n \le \frac{1} {b_0 en!},\quad b_n \le \frac{1} {a_0 en!} \tag{2}$$
Neither $a_0$ nor $b_0$ can vanish, because  $f(0)g(0)=e^{-1}\ne 0$.

The inequalities (2) imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}  a_n^{1/n}=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}  b_n^{1/n}=0$.

Caution: the inequalities (2) **do not** imply $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} =0$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=0$